# Can't import non-default fonts, into monogame

Tags: c#, fonts, xna, monogame

I have tried for some time now to import fonts, (into Monogame) that ain't the default, and it just wont work. I googled it many times but none of the answers I found solved it. So does any of you might know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "I have tried for some time now to import fonts..." okay, what have you tried? Can you please tell us where you are stuck?

Comment: I don't really have the exact answer to your problem but I do have a workaround that might help using BitmapFonts instead of SpriteFonts. http://dylanwilson.net/bmfont-rendering-with-monogame-extended

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with 3.7.1.189, and fixed it by right-clicking the font .otf file and selecting Install for All Users. You may get a UAC prompt, click Allow or Yes. This fixed MonoGame's Pipeline Tool for me so I could use a custom font.

Answer (score 2):

It was hard to find info for this on the Internet since the process has changed with the addition of the Monogame Pipeline Tool (http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=Pipeline). This documentation is for Monogame 3.4.

How to add a Font and use it in MonoGame 3.4:

1. Grab the font you want to use (check the license to make sure you can use it).
2. Install the font into your operating system.
3. Open the Fonts control panel to verify the proper name of the font.
   *Hint: It's not the file name, and it's not necessarily the name of the font in the Fonts control panel's main page.*

   a. Right-click the font & go to properties

   b. Note the "Title" of the font: [image: Font Title].

   *In the screen shot, the font is "Plasmatica" but the Font's control panel shows it as "Plasmatica Regular". For the rest of this I'll be using Plasmatica Italic which happens to be the same in both places.*
4. In the MonoGame Pipeline tool, create a ".spritefont" file: [image: Add New Item]

   a. Choose "SpriteFont Description" and give it a name. 
   *I suggest something like "FontName_FontStyle_FontSize" eg: PlasmaticaItalic12.*
5. Open the new SpriteFont file in a text editor (double click it in MonoGame Pipeline). Change the  XML node to be the same name from the font's properties in the Font control panel. [image: SpriteFont XML]
6. Save & Build your MonoGame Pipeline project. If things are correct so far, you should see this in your output:

   > c:/[path to content directory]/Content/GUI/Fonts/PlasmaticaItalic12.spritefont
   >
   > Building Font C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\PlasmaNormalItalic.ttf
   >
   > Using DXT Compression
7. Now your code can load & use the font using this:

   > SpriteFont font = Content.Load( "Gui/Fonts/PlasmaticaItalic12" );
   >
   > spriteBatch.DrawString( font, "Hello World!", Vector2(0,0), Color.White );
   >
   > // Where Content is the Content variable (type: ContentManager) of the Game class - the subclass of your main
   >   game class - game1.cs in all the examples. And spriteBatch is, well a SpriteBatch.

P.S. If you have trouble, check to be sure the output of the Pipeline tool is included in your project. Mine is called "Content.mgcb". Mine was included since I started with a sample from Monogame. You should probably it to Visual Studio "in place" - meaning don't "Add an Existing File" because that will make a copy. You want an actual link or include the directory structure to the file. Fix the properties of the file (in VS) to set the build action to "MonoGameContentReference". The "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Do Not Copy"

Good luck! I'm enjoying Monogame so far but it's a bit complicated to get all the parts setup correctly.

Comment: I'm finding with version 3.7.1.189 of the Content Pipeline tool I need to include the font file with the spritefont description and font name needs to match the file name.